# ScrollView dos not work

Tags: android, scrollview

Dear All experts I have problem with using scrollView anyone please help.. the Error is showing that the ScrollView is useless and also in other form of mine is shows the same , how can I solve this and how can I make my forms and activities been scroll ??

`

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:contentDescription="@+id/button1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="android:buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="goToMain"
        android:text="@string/log_in" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="android:buttonStyle "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="register"
        android:text="@string/registration" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

Comment: ScrollView hosts only one child View. You can't add more than one view in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a child container as `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout` in your `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView 
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        ... >

        <!-- Your views: TextView, LinearLayout, etc. -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

According to [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place **one child in it containing the entire contents** to scroll

Comment: Dear Fllo , I did that also but still I have yellow warning Icon

Comment: Where do you have a warning? **A *warning alert* isn't an error**, just an information that you need to care (or not, if you know what you do) about. Maybe it's the heights which are not properly set (ScrollView `width/height=fill_parent` / First child Layout `width=fill_parent`/`height=wrap_content`).. or an id not set. Where do you get the warning?

Comment: next to ScrollView tag , it's saying "This ScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless"

Comment: how can I add parent layout ? where to add ?

Comment: I didn't say *you must*, I said *you should* don't have a parent but, if you want it, try to add **another child** at the same step of the ScrollView like the RelativeLayout here:  `<LinearLayout > <ScrollView > <LinearLayout > <OtherViews /> </LinearLayout> </ScrollView> <RelativeLayout > <OtherViews /> </RelativeLayout> </LinearLayout>`. As you can see, the 1st LinearLayout has two children so it's not useless.. It all depends of your layout. But it's not an error, just an advice. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

"Scrollview can host only one direct child"

Put all your stuff in some Layout e.g LinearLayout

Comment: Dear Gupta you are right , but in that way arranging the position of each field will be difficult , there is no way to have scroll in multiply layer ?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the other fields in a single Layout.. Like linear layout,relative layout. Your whole code should look like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@+id/button1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/username"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="android:buttonStyle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="goToMain"
                android:text="@string/log_in" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="android:buttonStyle "
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="register"
                android:text="@string/registration" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: u should put all the stuff in another linear layout.. 
Its should be like this.
<Linear Layout ...>
 <ScrollView ...>
  <Linear Layout ...>
    your stuff
  </Linear Layout ...>
 </ScrollView ...>
</Linear Layout ...>
It Might show a warning that parent linear layout is useless. But dont bother it. It wont affect the working.. :)